# C - Memory Leak Issue with array when items are overwritten

Tags: c, arrays, memory-leaks, glib

Have not touched C in quite some time and am reviewing some code. I see an array of JsonObjects and they are attempting to free a JsonObject* before it is overwritten in an array. I am seeing a memory leak and am investigating the root cause. Any insight on the root cause and suggestions for better implementation are welcome. Below is a snippet:

```
#include <json-glib/json-glib.h> 

MAX_SAMPLES = 5;
JsonObject* array[MAX_SAMPLES];
int index = 0;
bool maxSamplesReached = false;

void foo(){
    if(index >= MAX_SAMPLES){
        index = 0;
        maxSamplesReached = true;   
    }

    if(maxSamplesReached){
       json_object_unref(array[index]); 
       //array[index] = NULL //does not help
    }

    JsonObject *root = json_object_new();
    JsonNode *node = json_node_new(JSON_NODE_VALUE);
    json_node_set_string(node, "value");
    json_object_set_member(root, "key", node);

    array[index++] = root;
}
```

Calling json_object_unref(array[index]) should free the previous memory and the new object should be equal to the freed memory correct? So I am expecting the memory to not grow but this is definitely leaking memory. foo() is called frequently and the idea is that the history of samples are synced to a server, in the event that maxSamplesReached = true, MAX_SAMPLES will be synced.

Comment: I know there are duplicates of this question but I just can't seem to find them right now. The problem isn't that the memory leaks (unless there's a bug in the library) but that the operating system just doesn't unmap the pages from your process right away. The memory is released as it should, and will be available to the OS if it needs it.

Comment: Where is json_node_free ?

Comment: and also, you firstly reset index to 0, and then use it for json_object_unref?

Comment: would you not need to call `json_object_unref()` on all members of `array` not just the first one?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for the comment! I will try to find the other threads.

Comment: @dmi I did a simple unit test that added a large number items to the array and then called json_object_unref(root) on all of the items, no memory leak. Adding json_node_free(node), or better yet, json_object_foreach_member(root, forEachMemberCB, NULL) actually crashes the app before or after json_object_unref(root).

Comment: @ChrisTurner, we do not want to call json_object_unref() on all the members of the array as we want to send that data to a server eventually, so in this implementation, we are just overwriting oldest data in an LRU type of way

Comment: @gareoke do you call it after you send the data though? we can only comment based on the code you've shown us and it looks like once the array is full, it frees the first element, but then starts overwriting the other ones